# Boost Asio Async Connection Race Condition?

Tags: c++, concurrency, boost-asio

I am looking at the [Boost Asio Blocking TCP Client timeout](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp) example with a special interest on how connection timeouts are implmented. How do we know from the documentation that the callback handler and subsequent checks don't introduce a race condition?

The Asynchronous connection command

```
boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, iter, var(ec) = _1);
```

executes the `var(ec) = _1` which is the handler for setting the error code once execute. Alternatively, a full and explicit lambda could be used here.

At the same time, the `check_deadline` function appears to be
called by the `deadline_` member. The timeout appears to be enforced by having the deadline forcibly close the socket whereup we assume that perhaps that the blocking statement

```
do io_service_.run_one(); while (ec == boost::asio::error::would_block);
```

would return. At first I thought that the error code must be atomic but that doesn't appear to be the case. Instead, [this page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html), appears to indicate that the strand model will work whenever the calls to the socket/context come from the same thread.

So we assume that each callback for the deadline (which is in Asio) and the handle for the `async_connect` routine will not be run concurrently. Pages such as [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) in the documentation hint that handlers will only execute during `run()` calls which will prevent the command `while(ec == whatever)` from behind executed during the handler currently changing its value.

How do I know this explicitly? What in the documentation that tells me explicitly that no handlers will ever execute outside these routines? If true, the page on the [proactor design pattern](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) must infer this, but never explicitly where the "Initiator" leads to the "Completion Handler".

The closes I've found is the [documentation for io_context](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html) saying

> Synchronous operations on I/O objects implicitly run the io_context
> object for an individual operation. The io_context functions run(),
> run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or poll_one() must be called
> for the io_context to perform asynchronous operations on behalf of a
> C++ program. Notification that an asynchronous operation has completed
> is delivered by invocation of the associated handler. Handlers are
> invoked only by a thread that is currently calling any overload of
> run(), run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or poll_one() for the
> io_context.

This implies that if I have one thread running the `run_one()` command then its control path will wait until a handler is available and eventually wind its way through a handler whereupon it will return and check ther `ec` value.

Is this correct and is "Handlers are invoked only by a thread that is currently calling any overload of run(), run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or poll_one() for the io_context." the best statement to find for understanding how the code will always function? Is there any other exposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asio library is gearing up to be standardized as NetworkingTS. This part is indeed the deal:

> Handlers are invoked only by a thread that is currently calling any overload of run(), run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or poll_one() for the io_context

You are correct in concluding that the whole example is 100% single-threaded¹. There cannot be a race.

I personally feel the best resource is the [Threads and Boost.Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) page:

> - By only calling io_context::run() from a single thread, the user's code can avoid the development complexity associated with synchronisation. For example, a library user can implement scalable servers that are single-threaded (from the user's point of view).

It also reiterates the truth from earlier:

> [...] the following guarantee:
>
> - Asynchronous completion handlers will only be called from threads that are currently calling io_context::run().

---

¹ except potential internal service threads depending on platform/extensions, as the [threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html) page details

Comment: As a nice insight into how to read "standardese-y" documentation like Asio's, I enjoyed reading @VinnieFalco's write-ups on [composed operations](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6aygos/boostasio_asynchronous_composed_operation_tutorial/). They make exceptionally clear how you have to read Asio docs with a standards mindset. Few words are accidental, and many "emergent" properties are not redundantly described. E.g. the interpretations in [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6aygos/boostasio_asynchronous_composed_operation_tutorial/dhitp5v/) are especially illustrative.